# Finite process in Revuz-Yor

Tags: stochastic-processes, quadratic-variation

In chapter 1 definition 2.3 of Revuz's and Yor's Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion is defined the quadratic variation of a real-valued process $X$ as a *finite process* $\left(\langle X, X\rangle_t\right)_t$ such that for all $t\in\mathbf{R}_+$ and every sequence $(\pi_n)_n$ of subdivisions of $[0,t]$ such that $\|\pi_n\| \to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$ we have $T_t^{\pi_n} (X) \to \langle X, X\rangle_t$ in probability as $n\to +\infty$, where if $\pi = \{0 = t_0 < \ldots < t_k = t\}$ is a subdivision of $[0,t]$ we note $\|\pi\| = \max_{i=0,\ldots,k-1} |t_{i+1} - t_i|$ and $T_t^{\pi} (X) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} \left( X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_i}\right)^2$.

What is intended by *finite process* exacty ? (It does not seem to be defined in the book.) Does this means a process $(Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with values in $\overline{\mathbf{R}}$ such that :

1. $\forall t\in\mathbf{R}_+, Y_t \in \mathbf{R}$
2. $\forall t\in\mathbf{R}_+$, $\mathbf{P}$-a.s. $Y_t \in \mathbf{R}$
3. $\mathbf{P}$-a.s. $\forall t\in\mathbf{R}_+$, $Y_t \in \mathbf{R}$

I don't think it can be (1) but I am hesitating between (2) and (3) even if I would go for (2).

Comment: It's 3/. 2/ is for "modification" concept, 3/ corresponds to "up to evanescence" or "indistinguishability" concept which roughly means "a.s. on the path space" as you have written. But observe that for continuous processes both concepts are equivalent and it's true "càd" processes aswell. Have a look in Karatzas & Shreve's book on BM where they present plenty facts (with proof or as exercises) on this in the first chapter, or in George Lowther's fantastic blog "almost sure" lemma 1 here : https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/stochastic-processes-indistinguishability-and-modifications/

Comment: Continuous process meaning a.s. continuous paths.